# When would a process cause paging in linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, paging

Today, i received few alerts about swapping activity of 3000KB/sec. This linux box have very few process running and has total 32GB of RAM. When i logged and did execute free, i did not see any thing suspicious. The ratio of free memory to used in (buffers/cache) row, was high enough(25GB in free, to 5GB in usage).

1. So i am wondering what are main causes of paging on linux system
2. How does swappiness impact paging
3. How long does a page stay in Physical RAM before it is swapped out. What controls this behavior on linux?
4. Is it possible that even if there is adequate free physical RAM, but a process's memory access pattern is such that data is spread over multiple pages. Would this cause paging?
   For example consider a 5GB array, such that the program access 5GB in a loop, although slowly, such that pages which are not used , are swapped out. Again, keep in mind, that even if buffer is 5GB, there could be 20GB of physical RAM available.

UPDATE:
The linux vendor is RHEL 6.3, kernel version 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64

Comment: Can you paste the output of `free` during the high paging? The most likely cause of high paging is a large number of memory-mapped file pages being dirtied.

Comment: This question is great but must specify Linux version. People are always changing or tuning these algorithms.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Would dirty pages cause paging, even if there is large number of physical RAM available?

Comment: @Jimm: Yes. The pages have to be written back to disk eventually if they're memory-mapped file pages.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz would you know how linux determines mmap over brk during malloc?

Comment: @Jimm: That won't matter because those pages are private, so they don't have to get written to disk.